# Getting file permission on read while using MMF

Tags: file-io, ipc, file-permissions, memory-mapped-files, locked-files

I have two processes. One writing in a memory mapped file using .NET 4 MemoryMappedFiles and the other reading the file using FileStream in .NET 3.5 (MONO). Everything works fine when I get the permission, no problem reading or writing the file. The problem is to obtain a permission.

Writing MMF (the Writer):

```
MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile
                           (filenameToMap, FileMode.Create, "Something",
                           Marshal.SizeOf(objectToMap), MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Reading MMF (the Reader):

```
new FileStream(filenameToMap, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

First I start the Writer, then the Reader.

I tested it using this naive approach:

```
while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                  new FileStream(mapPath + "map.mp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite);
                    break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

After roughly 10 seconds, the Reader usually gets permission and everything runs smooth. If I would catch the exception, it would throw:

> IOException: Sharing violation on path
>   C:\path   at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor
>   (System.String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous,
>   FileOptions options) [0x00000] in
>   :0

Any idea why these two processes don't share the file properly from beginning?